# Ending a loop to return to next sequence

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a text adventure in C#. Ive only been coding for a few days and I can't find how to do this.
I was trying to to ask a yes or no question and yes would go to the next question in the story. If its a no I wanted it to start a loop till it forces the player to type the correct answer (yes). After the user types yes how do i get it to exit the loop and move to the next part of the story? If this doesn't make sense ask me and I will try to reexplain.
Here is how i got it to at least go to the next section. I would like it to loop till the user says yes. I would like it to loop though.

```
using System;

namespace Game.of.words.forgotten.period
{
  class Program
  {
    public static player currentplayer = new player();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.Clear();
      Start();
      Encounters.Firstencounter();
    }

    static void Start()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Game Of Words The Forgotten Period");
      Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my world. What is your name? ");
      string currentplayer = Console.ReadLine();
    
      Console.Clear();
            
      Console.WriteLine("We are happy to see you here " + currentplayer + " !");
      Console.WriteLine("I bet you are wondering where you are and why you are here. Is that correct? (Yes) or (No)");
      string input = Console.ReadLine();
      if (input.ToLower() == "yes")
      {
        //Yes
        Console.WriteLine("I thought as much.I am incredibly skilled at the confusion arts");
      }
      else 
      {
        //no
        Console.WriteLine("Well I just assumed because... I mean I took all this time to make this a crazy experience to");
        Console.WriteLine(" confuse you but I guess you are too smart for that.");
        Console.WriteLine("Please just say yes.");
        Console.ReadLine();
              
        if (input.ToLower() == "no")
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Okay fine. You can be like that");
        }
        else 
          Console.Write("I thought as much. I am incredibly skilled at the confusion arts.");

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("As you see we are in the middle of no where. Surounded by Tall mountains and no trees.");
      Console.WriteLine("I bet you can feel the slight breeze and smell the fragrece of the flowers all around us");
      Console.WriteLine("Do you want me to telaport us into town or do you walk through the flowers and watch the clouds for a while? ");
      Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is another example. I am not understanding something.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("hello Player what is your name? ");
        String Name= Console.ReadLine();
        string j = ("June");
        if (Name != j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + Name);
            while (Name != j)
            {              
                Console.WriteLine("Thats not your name");
                // Creates endless loop. If I add a readline it will
                //print hello michael and then that is not your name will
                //Repeat on every enter.
                //If I put a break; it just prints both and ends. 
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a number to each question. If the player says "no", move the current question to the one where the loop starts.

Comment: We don't have enough context.  Show the code you have that's causing the problem.

Comment: welcome - please provide what you have tried.

Comment: You don't have any loops in your code.  You probably want a `while (something is true) {...}` type of loop for what you are asking.  BTW, you have currentplayer declared as a player class and a string in your code.

Comment: @LarsTech Oh yeah I was following a tutorial and he created a class file for the player. I tried the while but once I was in it I couldn't seem to stop it. If i type yes it continued as if i said no. Thats why I gave up and changed it to this.haha

Comment: If you would have posted your loop code, we could have fixed it for you.

Comment: In that player name loop, you only ask for the name once and then continue to test that value. Read a new name instead

Answer (score 0):

on the second example you don't really need the if statement, you can use the while loop.

```
string exitName = "exit";
Console.Write($"hello Player what is your name? (to skip the while loop you must type {exitName}) {Environment.NewLine}");
String Name = Console.ReadLine();
while (Name != exitName)//while the name does not equal 'exit' you will stay in the loop
{
    Console.WriteLine("You did not exit!");
    Console.WriteLine($"You entered {Name} you must enter {exitName} to exit this loop!");
                    Name = Console.ReadLine();
}
    
Console.WriteLine("press any key to end game");
Console.ReadLine();
```

In your first example  you have the lines

```
Console.WriteLine("Please just say yes.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

this should be

```
Console.WriteLine("Please just say yes.");
input = Console.ReadLine();
```

otherwise you aren't assigning anything to input again.